# Probability of teacher being in the last room: $\frac 45$ divided by $8$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A student is looking for his teacher. There is a 4/5 chance that the teacher is in one of 8 rooms, and he has no specific room preferences. Student checked 7 of the rooms, but the teacher wasn't in any of them. What's the probability that he is in one of the 8 rooms?

I tried dividing the P(4/5) by 8 and getting probability of teacher being in any one room of 0.1, and then subtracting 0.1*7 from 1 to get 0.3 - probability that he is in the last room. However that's not the right answer.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: Post edit, use Bayes Theorem. What is the total probability that you'd fail to find the teacher in seven rooms? What portion of that is explained by the teacher being in room $8$?

Comment: @lulu is total prob that you won't find him in 7 rooms 0.175? And not sure how him not being in a room is explained by him being in a room? 1-0.175?

Comment: Not following.  A priori, there are $9$ mutually exclusive events which are possible:  he might be in any one of the $8$ rooms or he might be elsewhere.  Only two of those $9$ events result in the first seven rooms being empty.  What is the probability that one of those two events occurs?

Comment: @lulu 1/9 a priori and 1/2 a posteriori, after first 7 rooms have been checked? And total probability for first 8 outcomes is 0.8, and last one, him not being in any rooms is 0.2? But what do i do with the 1/9 (considering that is actaully the right answer to your question)?

Comment: The $9$ mutually exclusive events are not equally probable, so the $\frac 19$ is incorrect.

Comment: Though, you could approach the problem that way if you are a bit creative about it.  Let's imagine that there were $10$ equally probable mutually exclusive outcomes:  $8$ rooms and $2$ "elsewhere".  Now each event has probability$\frac 1{10}$ so, having checked $7$ rooms there are $3$ equally probable options remaining.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have found out:

- $0.1$ is the probability that the teacher is in a particular room, for any of the $8$ particular rooms (assuming that we haven't started looking for him).
- $0.7$ is the probability that the teacher is in one of the first $7$ rooms checked.
- $1-0.7$ is the probability that the teacher is not in one of those rooms i.e. that he is in the last room *or not in any of those rooms*.

What you are actually asked for is the probability that the teacher is in the $8$th room, *given that* the first $7$ rooms are empty.

*Before* we checked the rooms, there was a $0.1$ chance that the teacher was in the $8$th room, and a $0.2$ chance that the teacher was not in the $8$ rooms.

*After* we checked the rooms, one of these two options *must* be the case, and the *ratio* of their likelihoods remains the same, so the chance that it is the $8$th room is:

$$\frac{0.1}{0.1+0.2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

The chance that the teacher is not there is $2/3$, preserving that this option is twice as likely as the teacher being in a particular room.

In general, this idea of relative likelihood being preserved is encapsulated in [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem), which you could use to formulate the same answer.

Comment: Thank you! Will have to do more similar questions.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: The fact that you eliminated some possibilities changes the probabilities of other possibilities _(consider: I flip a fair coin and tell you the result is not heads. Is there still a 50% chance of it being tails?)_. If it helps, you can think of there being 10 rooms, with every room having an equal 10% chance. Initially there's an 80% chance he's in one of the first 8 rooms, but what about after checking the first 7?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: got it, thanks. It's a bit funny that math can provide 2 answers on exactly the same question just after some time has passed by. --- There is a 4/5 chance that the teacher is in one of 8 rooms. What's the probability that he is in one of the 8 rooms? Real answer: it depends on how many rooms you have checked. Not the answer I would have given until today.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Number the rooms with $i=1,2,\dots,8$.

Let $E_i$ denote the event that the teacher is in room $i$.

Now find:$$P(E_8|E_1^c\cap\cdots\cap E_7^c)$$
Beware that the events are mutually exclusive with:$$P(E_1\cup\cdots\cup E_8)=\frac45\text{ and }P(E_1)=\cdots=P(E_8)$$